# Multiple lines in Silverlight's autocompletebox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Is it possible to use Enter key to break lines in Silverlight's `AutocompleteBox`? Currently my binded data contains new line characters and box displays it properly (grows vertically), however pressing the **Enter** key does not break the line. Is there any way to achieve behaviour similar to `TextBox` with property `AcceptsReturn` set to `True`? Any examples or ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, posting in case someone else needed:

```
public class MultilineAutocompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            this.Text = string.Format("{0}\n", this.Text);

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```